# Export image from file latex

Tags: graphics

I want to make the online exam for my student with a google form, but when I export images of questions, they are too big (full A4 paper), I want to export images of questions to be small corresponding heigh and width of them.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to crop a document to the text/images it contains the best way is to use [`standalone`](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en).

This would require you to define a standalone document for each of your questions. each question will generate a cropped pdf.

Another option is to wrap each question in the [`preview`](https://ctan.org/pkg/preview?lang=en) environment. Each such environment will also generate a cropped pdf.

I would also advise OP to search exporting from latex. One can find good pages such as [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats)

**Note:**
This answer simply points OP in the direction of packages he might use. If OP would supply us with a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), we could see which fits his problem best

Answer (score 0):

One can set your width and height with `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4cm]{mypicture}`, usually just width enought. There is also [`exam` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en).